# Make Office Portable for Linux?

Tags: microsoft-office-2010, centos-5, portable-apps

I have an Microsoft Office 2010 license, and I wanted to know if there was a way to have this suite as a portable app (or apps) and use it from Linux. (I'm using CentOS 5.9, by the way)

Do you know how can i make it so?

Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Yes, found for Windows only. I mean, .exe, strictly talking. That's why I'm asking. The question is not only if it's portable but if it works on Linux.

Comment: No, as you would need a portable version of WINE to go along with it...

Comment: Now, that's interesting. If I make a Portable version of Office, can I run it from CentOS having WINE already installed?

Comment: Assuming you have all .exe's registered with WINE, there is a good possibility.  WINE may also not fully support Office 2010, and even if it does, may not support the portable version...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [the official rating](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=31) suggests, the Office 2010 32-bit installer and individual apps work reasonably well under Wine.

Regarding portable versions, no such official (and legal) version of Office exists to my knowledge, and so obviously none has been tested for compatibility with Wine. The sole exception (in terms of portability, not Wine compatibility) is one that runs from an [Office Starter To-Go Device](http://www.howtogeek.com/98855/how-to-create-a-portable-usb-version-of-microsoft-office-starter-2010/), which is not available for download but can be freely created at any time if you have access to this ad-supported version of Office.

So basically your choices are restricted to *installing* and using Office 2010 under Wine, or installing Windows and Office in a Virtual Machine in Linux.

Comment: Yes, I also researched. And under that (confirmed) premise, you're right. Thanks for the answer =)

Comment: What about running Office.exe from that Office Starter To-Go Device using Wine? Does it work? Is it legal?